# Adding mouse click listener in tab in jtabbedpane in java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have the design as follows. [image]
        When i click visualize i get the scatter plot. 
    Now what i want to do is to change the graph when the
     user click on tabs. I want each tab to handle different 
    graph .How can i do that?
        The main problem is i am not being able to 
    add mouse click listener to add actions to each tab,
     that is my problem. How can i do that?

Comment: Couldn't you use a `JTabbedPane ChangeListener`? It gets notified when the selected tab is changed. In this listener you could check for the present tab and show the corresponding graph.

Answer (score 2):

Tabs change without a mouse.  Typically through program logic such as when the tabbed view first appears with a default selection or with keyboard mnemonics assigned to a tab.  Adding a mouse listener would miss those cases.

As Stefan suggested add a [Changelistener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#addChangeListener-javax.swing.event.ChangeListener-) to the JTabbedPane and you will be notified no matter when or what causes the tabs to change.

```
tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Tab index: " + tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex());
    }
});
```

Example [here](http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-detect-tab-selection-changes-in-jtabbedpane/).

To change your contextual view based on the tabbed selected (scatter plot) you can:

- If the plot is the same yet the data changes then update the model
  behind the plot and refresh the plot view.  API's with [MVC patterns](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) such as [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) will allow you to do this.
- If the plots or views are substantially different for each tab use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to switch the plot views.